# Does upgrading PixelSense to Windows 8 loses features?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, signalr, pixelsense

By default, the operative system of the PixelSense SUR40 is Win 7 [PixelSense specs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_PixelSense#Samsung_SUR40_with_Microsoft_PixelSense)

I am thinking on upgrading (or dual boot) the PixelSense table to Windows 8 in order to take fully advantage of the .Net Framework 4.5 features such as WebSockets (with SignalR).

Has anyone performed that upgrade? If so, is there any lost of features I should be aware? Some examples I am afraid of losing are:

- The surface mode.
- The calibration and management tools.
- Surface "debugging" mode.
- SDK based functionality: Tags, Blobs and native PixelSense touch overall (orientation, etc)

Thank you so much in advance!

EDIT: I found a piece of my answer thanks to Gian Paolo Santopaolo [here](http://thedarksideof.net/post/Win8-WinRT-on-large-format-multitouch-displays-and-the-need-of-Surface-SDK.aspx)  Good enough to know that:

- Surface input (tags, blobs, orientation) would not be supported,
- Nor would the default Kiosk mode (you can get something similar to Kiosk mode by changing the proper Windows configuration, reg keys, etc)
- Nor the surface shell.

If you know about anything else that you consider relevant that would be missing, please post it! (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated it. you can read about it [here](http://www.thedarksideof.net/post/Windows-8-on-Samsung-SUR40-for-Microsoft-PixelSense.aspx).

I’ve to advice that if you are going to try to do this, Windows 8 on SUR40 is totally unsupported, and there is an high risk that you will fail and the result will be a broken SUR40 so if you decide to do it you will to at your own risk, my advice is not to try it, I did it only for testing purpose

hth
Gian Paolo